# Why can't I connect the File's Owner to new Views in iOS SDK?

Tags: iphone, ios4

I am working on an iPhone SDK project using Xcode 4 Preview. I am in the IFB view and have deleted the default view icon and brought in two new views which I have named Portrait and Landscape. I should be able to control drag from the File's Owner to the two views to connect them, but the usual HUD does not appear and I cannot connect them. There is no code relevant to this task so I can't share that and a screenshot would be meaningless. I would appreciate any assistance on getting them to connect.

thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, check that the class File's Owner is associated with has IBOutlet slots with the appropriate types for your new views. If File's Owner is not the right class, you can change it in the inspector panel. If the class lacks the slots, add them to the header and then try again.

Comment: Here is what I have in the .h file: @interface SwapViewController : UIViewController {
    UIView *landscape;
    UIView *portrait;

Comment: I've not done much iOS development, but on Mac OS X these slots would have to be marked with the IBOutlet qualifier before IB would "see" them… I suspect the same is true for iOS.